# How does a DSLR's mirror mechanism work?

Tags: dslr, slr, mirror

I'm wondering how the mirror in a DSLR or SLR camera is flipped up (and back down again) when a photo is taken.

Is this mirror typically actuated by a motor, magnet, spring and gravity, or something else? If there are any specific examples, I'd also love to see how this mechanism actually looks.

Comment: Have you searched online? I know I've seen this before, someone even filmed it working with an ultra-high-speed camera.

Comment: I've seen a few videos, although it's a bit difficult to see what's going on, or how any of the actuation is happening.

Comment: This article on the Nikon D4 mirror box patent diagrams may be interesting. I assume the patent describes how it works http://www.photographybay.com/2011/09/29/nikon-pro-dslr-d4-patent-diagrams/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today, most DSLR mirrors are operated by a dedicated motor. Return springs are used to move the mirror back into position. Some DSLR's have two mirror motors. One to raise and one for return. Here is a video that shows how the Canon EOS 7D Mark II operates: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLU5oygrkpw

[image: 7D Mk II mirror]

Comment: Nice! Thanks; The precision of such a device is impressive.

Comment: `S/Hear/Here/` for some reason I can't fix it myself.

Comment: The 7D Mark II is not typical, as it was one of the first motor driven return mirrors incorporated into anything other than a professional "flagship" model.